# how can I drop low correlated features

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, statistics, correlation

I am making a preprocessing code for my LSTM training. My csv contains more than 30 variables. After applying some EDA techniques, I found that half of the features can be drop and they don't make any effect on training.

Right now I am dropping such features manually by using `pandas`.

I want to make a code which can drop such features automaticlly.
I wrote a code to visualize heat map and correlation in this way:

```
#I am making a class so this part is from preprocessing.
# self.data is a Dataframe which contains all csv data

def calculateCorrelationByPearson(self):
        columns = self.data.columns
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
        sns.heatmap(data=self.data.corr(method='pearson'), annot=True, fmt='.2f', 
                      linewidths=0.5, cmap='Blues')
        plt.show()
        for column in columns:
            corr = stats.spearmanr(self.data['total'], self.data[columns])
            print(f'{column} - corr coefficient:{corr[0]}, p-value:{corr[1]}')
```

This gives me a perfect view of my features and relationship with each other.

Now I want to drop columns which are not important.
Let's say correlation less than 0.4.

How can I apply this logic in to my code?

Comment: If you are training a multivariate model, I would be careful about dropping features based on a univariate correlation with your model objective/target variable as a general approach.  Also, be careful using a linear correlation measure to drop variables in case there may be a non-linear effect.  There are often multivariate or non-linear effects that might not be obvious based on a linear correlation coefficient.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right. I am doing multiple trainings and testings to see the results. This question is just a part of my one training. Actually multivariate model training is quite complicated than I used to think.

Comment: When I'm looking for a general approach to pruning the variables in my model, then I might use some "variable selection" technique using permutation importance for estimating variable importance in the model or perhaps a genetic algorithm to select the 'important' variables from the perspective of the ability to explain variance in the target variable.  These approaches essentially involve fitting many model variants in order to assess the variable importance, and then use that to narrow down the field of variables before doing a final model fit and performance evaluation.

Comment: Do you have any examples which is okay to share here ?

Comment: For Variable selection approaches, it would probably take me a while to dig into some of my prior projects and put together a working example.  There are lots of good resources on the web, though, for using approaches like Permutation Importance or Genetic Algorithms.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me dig on genetic algorithms. I think this will be helpfull: https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-with-genetic-algorithms-7dd7e02dd237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach to remove variables with a correlation coef value below some threshold:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import spearmanr

data = pd.DataFrame([{"A":1, "B":2, "C":3},{"A":2, "B":3, "C":1},{"A":3, "B":4, "C":0},{"A":4, "B":4, "C":1},{"A":5, "B":6, "C":2}])
targetVar = "A"
corr_threshold = 0.4

corr = spearmanr(data)
corrSeries = pd.Series(corr[0][:,0], index=data.columns) #Series with column names and their correlation coefficients
corrSeries = corrSeries[(corrSeries.index != targetVar) & (corrSeries > corr_threshold)] #apply the threshold

vars_to_keep = list(corrSeries.index.values) #list of variables to keep
vars_to_keep.append(targetVar)  #add the target variable back in
data2 = data[vars_to_keep]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot BioData41. I think, it's better for me to drop features with genetic algorithm. Using a simple correlation method is not good in my case because of non -linear effect in features. However for simple approach (if anyone is searching for dropping features)your code works. Thank you again.